# Html element with AngularJS attribute generate after init AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've AngularJS issue when there are some elements(button) generate dynamically or generate after init AngularJS. Source code below shows the button not able to trigger the ng-click attribute. Any ideas that can trigger the AngularJS attribute after init the AngularJS. Thanks.

```
 OperationFormatter: function (value, row) {
    var operations = [];

    operations.push('<button class="btn-mini glyphicon glyphicon-edit" ng-
                click="myFunc()" title="Shared_Edit"></button>');

    return operations.join(' ');
// This function only can execute after init the AngularJS due to certain 
conditions.
}

$(function () {
MyCtrl();   
})

function MyCtrl($scope) {
var app = angular.module("appAffiliateInfo", []);
app.controller("ctrlBankInfo", function ($scope) {
    $scope.myFunc = function () {
        alert('ok');
    };
});
};
```

Comment: Is OperationFormatter inside angular app code or outside? If outside then it's not correct approach at all. If it's inside then you can make use of $compile to compile the element to be added to the dom dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to dynamically insert the generated HTML code in your template.
It cannot be done this way, as AngularJS already parsed your template at "runtime" and created all its watchers.

You have to use the `$compile` service, like so:

```
// scope: the scope containing the function called by ng-click
// htmlCode: your html code (as a string)  
var newElem = $compile(htmlCode)(scope);  

// use the proper code here, depending on what you want to achieve with the HTML element
document.body.appendChild(newElem[0]);
```

When "compiled" by $compile, the HTML code is parsed in order to create the required watchers. You *must* make sure that you provide the correct scope to $compile, or the function intended to ng-click will never be called.